# Can destruct used in implication in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

*destruct* can be used to split *and*, *or* in Coq. But it seems can also be used in implication?
For example, I want to prove `~~(~~P -> P)`

```
Lemma test P : ~~(~~P -> P).
Proof.
unfold not.
intro pffpf.
apply pffpf.
intro pff.
destruct pff.
intro p.
apply pffpf.
intro pff.
exact p.
Qed.
```

when `destruct pff.` it works fine, but I don't know why? Can anyone explain it for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `destruct` tactic works on implications if the conclusion of the implication is of inductive (or co-inductive) type. Hence it works on your example, because `False` is defined inductively. However, if we came up with a different definition of `False`, it might not necessarily work. For instance, the following script fails at the `destruct pff` line:

```
Definition False : Prop := forall A : Prop, A.
Definition not (P : Prop) : Prop := P -> False.

Lemma test P : not (not (not (not P) -> P)).
unfold not.
intro pffpf.
apply pffpf.
intro pff.
destruct pff. (* Fails here *)
intro p.
apply pffpf.
intro pff.
exact p.
Qed.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, by the way, what's a inductive type?

Comment: An inductive type in Coq is a data type defined with the `Inductive` keyword. These include things like natural numbers, pairs, lists, trees, etc., but also some propositions, like `True`, `False`, and others.