# Coq: working with inequalities (<>)

Tags: coq, proof, theorem-proving, coq-tactic

I'm trying to understand the logic about working with inequalities in Coq.

- When `<>` is present in the goal, doing `intros contra.` changes the goal to `False` and moves the goal to an hypothesis but with `<>` switched to `=`. I think I understand how it is sound. If I have as goal `a <> b`, then `a = b` as hypothesis would generate a contradiction.

  However, I can't do the opposite in Coq. If I have as goal `a = b`, I can't `intros contra.` in order to have `False` as goal and `a <> b` as hypothesis. **Would this `intros` be logically sound? Is it not supported just because it is never needed to complete a proof?**
- When `<>` is in an hypothesis `H`, doing `destruct H.` will remove the hypothesis (I can't do `destruct (H) eqn:H.`) and it will switch any goal to the same that `H` but with `<>` switched for `=`. **I don't understand the logic here**. If I have an hypothesis which is an inequality, I don't see how not having it is the same as having the equality as goal.

  **How an inequality is inductive to be used by `destruct`?**

  If I have a contradictory hypothesis G `0 <> 0`, in order to complete the proof and tell it is a contradiction, I need to do `destruct G. (* now the goal is 0 = 0 *). reflexivity.` **Why is it not possible to just do something like `inversion G.`, as you would do with an hypothesis `S n = 0`?.**

So I have, in fact, 4 related questions marked **in bold**.

Comment: `a <> b` is basically a shorthand for `a = b -> False`, where `False` is an empty inductive type. I think this question really should be separated into four different ones.

Comment: Argument for the splitting the question: I can answer the first question, cannot answer the second and the forth, and can link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999244/can-destruct-used-in-implication-in-coq) question  which is similar to the third.

Comment: I guess you are right @yeputons. But now, thanks to your comment and the answer, everything is answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would this `intros` [on a goal `a = b`] be logically sound?

If I understand your question, you want to know if it would be possible to 
have a goal `a = b`, call `intros contra`, and transform that into the goal `H : a <> b |- False`. This would be sound, but not derivable in Coq's basic constructive logic for `a` and `b` of arbitrary type: it asserts that the proposition `a = b` supports double-negation elimination (`~ (~ a = b) -> a = b`).  Coq does not support this because it would mean working in a different logical formalism.

> How an inequality is inductive to be used by `destruct`?

As yeputons remarked, `a <> b` is defined as `a = b -> False`, and falsity is inductively defined as the proposition with no constructors; thus, destructing something of type `False` simply completes the proof.  Furthermore, calling  `destruct` on something of type `A -> B` has roughly the effect of generating a goal of type `A`, feeding that proof into the implication to obtain a proof of `B`, and then calling `destruct` on that proof of `B`.  In your case, this means doing exactly what you described.

> Why is it not possible to just do something like `inversion G.`, as you would do with an hypothesis `S n = 0`?

My guess is that `inversion` is not as lenient as `destruct`, and is not extended to work on implications as I explained above.

Comment: Thanks, now it is clear. About the logic beyond `destruct H` changing `<>` to a goal with `=`, I finally understood. If I proof `=` then `<>` as hypothesis is a contradiction, so everything follows (principle of explosion).